# Apache restarting on its own and errors on log

Tags: apache, restart, centos7, error-log

I have three separate boxes running Apache 2.4, all with the same config and modules. On CentOS 7, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.

Two issues that could possibly be related. On one hand, I have not forced a restart, yet it would appear that apache restarted itself based on error_log being purged and having the below.

Second issue are the actual errors or warnings displayed. I can't figure out how to resolve them and if they could be the reason that Apache restarts itself in the first place, or be creating other issues elsewhere.

```
[Sun Jul 19 03:39:02.241577 2015] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 904] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jul 19 03:39:02.243161 2015] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 904] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 19 03:39:02.246337 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 904] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Sun Jul 19 03:39:02.292119 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 904] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 19 03:39:02.292151 2015] [core:notice] [pid 904] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Would appreciate any guidance?

Comment: Failed to mention that all three apaches restarted themselves almost at the same time, minutes of difference between them. Which puzzles me, as nobody has logged to those servers for many days, and the only cron job running as root is a rkhunter update.

Comment: Maybe a power outage? :-) Or an unsatisfied employee, also often the cause.

Comment: Not quite possible. Servers have an uptime of 6 days. So wasn't a reboot at the machine. Also, only I have access to these machines. They're in different data centres as well, in different geographies.

Comment: You can never really be sure about such things. But actually my comment was not meant that serious... Certainly the http servers got restarted according to the log entries. _Why_ that happend is something that we certainly cannot answer. Sometimes the log rotation relaunches the http server afterwards. You claim there is only one single cron job executed on those systems... I cannot really believe that, sorry.

Comment: [root@jupiter ~]# crontab -l
10 3    * * *    /usr/bin/rkhunter --cronjob --update --quiet
[root@jupiter ~]# uptime
 13:19:44 up 6 days, 13:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05

Comment: roots crontab is not the only place where cron jobs can be configured. Actually it is a very untypical location. Have a look at `/etc/cron.....`.

Comment: I assure you, these boxes have no other cron jobs (yet). Purposefully.

Comment: Then how are the log files rotated for example? Typically the installation of the OS implements a number of such jobs. So you have removed them all? _Why?_

Comment: The idea is to ensure I can troubleshoot the basics first, get the basic and most essential wrapped up. Log rotation takes 5 min, and shouldn't really have a business impact until after the server is in production. This way, I can ensure any errors that need resolving are unrelated to those other things. I like to switch things on, one at a time, with a lot of care. - that is not to say that I might be wrong, its just the way I preffer to do things in general

Comment: I don't see what has to be troubleshooted in system specific cron jobs which are essential for a system to work. But as you say, OK. Maybe then that was the issue? That a logfile got too big, the server failed to write to the logs and restarted? sorry, please understand that we cannot help here. Only you know what is happening on your systems.

Comment: No, that can't be the issue. Machine is not in production, sits idling most of the day :-/